# code for iPhone camera raw data processing

Tags: ios, xcode, camera

I am new to iOS programming and I am wondering whether there is a way to access the 10-bit or 12-bit  raw data from the camera with AVFoundation or other library in Xcode? If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can load the image into a `UIImage`, you can use Core Graphics to get the pixel buffer. I suspect it will be stored in memory as 16 bits per pixel, but try it out and see.

```
UIImage *image = ...

CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;                                     // get the CGImageRef
NSAssert(imageRef, @"Unable to get CGImageRef");

CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef);           // get the data provider
NSAssert(provider, @"Unable to get provider");

NSData *data = CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(provider));      // get copy of the data
NSAssert(data, @"Unable to copy image data");

NSInteger       bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef); // some other interesting details about image
NSInteger       bitsPerPixel     = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef);
CGBitmapInfo    bitmapInfo       = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
NSInteger       bytesPerRow      = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef);
NSInteger       width            = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSInteger       height           = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace       = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);
```

See [The Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101) for more information.

Comment: Hi, Rob. Do `CGImageRef` and `CGDataProviderRef` provide different image data here? How are they different? Thanks.

Comment: `CGImageRef` defines more high level information (width, height, bits per pixel, bitmap info (e.g. is it RGBA or ARGB or ...). `CGDataProviderRef` provides the pixel-by-pixel data. So, get `CGImageRef`, and use that to get the `CGDataProviderRef` for that image. Note, do not mistake this for the "raw" file from your camera. But once it's been converted to a `UIImage`/`CGImageRef`, this is how you get pixel data.

Comment: I always mistakenly thought that the `raw` file was the `CGDataProviderRef`? Raw file contains just pixel infos, right? Forgot where I read this here on SO. Thanks.

Comment: It depends upon what you mean by "raw". In the camera world, "raw" often refers to the manufacturer's (often proprietary) format (e.g. Nikon NEF, Canon CRW, etc.). It includes lots of other stuff (EXIF and other meta data, JPG thumbnails, etc.). The `CGDataProviderRef` just contains the pixel-by-pixel and channel-by-channel data, but not this other information. So, for example, if you really need to know if the camera captured 8, 10, 12, or 14 bits per channel, `CGProviderRef` is not adequate. If you just need to know what it captured, then it may be fine.

Comment: Just an update about the format obtained with AVFoundation from the back camera of iPhone 5S can only have three formats:1. kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange
2. kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange
3. kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up an `AVCaptureSession` for camera capture and then use the delegate function:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

To capture the raw image data (sampleBuffer), refer to: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html